# oracle toad calling procedure with out parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

How do I see output result trying to call get_last_session procedure.
When I hit execute I get message that pl SQL procedure successfully completed but i don't see p_session_type_out parameter anywhere..

This is the code in editor.

```
DECLARE 
  P_USERNAME VARCHAR2(32767);
  P_SESSION_TYPE_OUT VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN 
  P_USERNAME := 'USER01';
  P_SESSION_TYPE_OUT := NULL;
  PCK_SESSION.GET_LAST_SESSION ( P_USERNAME, P_SESSION_TYPE_OUT );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('P_SESSION_TYPE_OUT = ' || P_SESSION_TYPE_OUT);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('');
END;
```

Comment: Is the question about  viewing dbms_output in Toad, or is it to do with calling procedures with out parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "View" >>> Click on "DBMS Output"

In bottom area, there will be one new panel will be attached with Near "Data Grid" panel.

Click on "Red" icon in the new panel, if that does not default "Green"
Then run your procedure it will print the output to DBMS output console.